# React Native Keyboard Animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am using [React Native Pager View](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pager-view) and trying to create a registration form. Each child view in Pager View contains another TextInput. When I scroll to another page, the keyboard tries to disappear for a second and appears again because my TextInput **autoFocus** property is set to true but I need a way to keep the keyboard always open whenever I scroll to the next page. I couldn't be able to find any solution.